# How do you add a trailing slash to a PUT request in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I do `this.model.save()` with a url, it sends a put request to the API at `/v1/store/api/customer/addresses/128583689` but the server needs a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and override the url function like this... https://gist.github.com/dericcrago/1886177

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Why post a link when you could post the code and some explanation?